# WebForms : Session variables null when an iframe is loaded

Tags: asp.net, session, iframe, webforms

I am working on a ASP.NET project which is already deployed on Azure.
I need to make some changes in it on my local system.
We have a login form , where on login we are setting a variable in session using :

> HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"] = "sessionid";

After login a form is loaded , also an iframe is added to a div in this page. We are setting source for this iframe as another test.aspx file. 
Session variable is reachable before iframe is loaded, but vanishes inside the iframe.

I have checked the timeout , it is set to 20 minutes , so this is surely not an issue.
Do I need to set some configuration in my project? Because this project works fine on server.

Comment: This is expected behaviour. ASP.NET is session less by default. What you need to do is assign a session variable in your application_start method in global.asax.cs

Comment: Where is `test.aspx` in relation to the main page - is it within the same site, same protocol, etc? Are you able to confirm that the session cookie is being passed to it?